# What is the meaning of sys.server_principals.default_language_name = null?

Tags: sql-server

When I execute

```
SELECT
  name,
  type,
  default_language_name
FROM sys.server_principals
```

I see that some users (server roles and certificates in particular) have a NULL `default_language_name`. What is the meaning of this value? What `LANGUAGE` gets used in this case?

**UPDATE**: Maybe `default_language_name` does not make sense for `SERVER_ROLE`, `CERTIFICATE_MAPPED_LOGIN` and `ASYMMETRIC_KEY_MAPPED_LOGIN` but if that's the case I'd like to find official documentation to that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [**Here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345412.aspx), `DefaultLanguage` Returns the login default language as stored in metadata. Returns NULL for non-SQL Server provisioned users, for example, Windows authenticated users.

SQL Server supports all languages that are supported by Windows operating systems.The English-language version of SQL Server is supported on all localized versions of operating systems.

> if `DefaultLanguage=NULL` , then it'll get the language setting from
>   Windows Multilingual User Interface Pack (MUI) settings.

[More Details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ee210665.aspx)